# Quiero mostrar los valores registrado en mi arreglo de objetos, pero no me despliega nada

Tags: c++, array, poo

como ya mencione, quiero visualizar los valores de mis arreglos. Creo que el problema es la función que cree en mi Cliente.cpp, pero no estoy seguro. Para que no sea tan largo, les comparto el código de 2 funciones.

No me marca error el programa (por lo menos) pero no hace nada mi función de InfoCliente. Cuando llamo la funcion InfoCliente me despliega la informacion de MostrarInfoCliente() de Cliente.cpp, pero no los valores de id_cliente, nombre, telefono, etc. Use un get para obtener los valores, pero no me regresa nada, sera porque necesito una variable que valla antes que llame el get, por ejemplo Nombre.getNombre() No estoy muy seguro como funcione en c++, vengo de java, y pues me dejaron pasar mi proyecto de java a c++, pero mi maestra solo nos enseño como crear clases.

---

Este es el codigo de Cliente.cpp

```
    #include "Cliente.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Cliente::getId_cliente(){return id_cliente;}

string Cliente::getNombre(){return nombre;}

string Cliente::getTelefono(){  return telefono;}

string Cliente::getDireccion(){ return direccion;}

string Cliente::getServicio(){  return servicio;}

//Metodos set
int Cliente::setId_cliente(int id){id_cliente=id;}

string Cliente::setNombre(string nombre){nombre=nombre;}

string Cliente::setTelefono(string telefono){telefono=telefono;}

string Cliente::setDireccion(string direccion){direccion=direccion;}

string Cliente::setServicio(string servicio){servicio=servicio;}

Cliente:: Const(int id, string nombre, string telefono, string direccion, string servicio)
{
    id_cliente=id;
    nombre=nombre;
    telefono=telefono;
    direccion=direccion;
    servicio=servicio;
}

void Cliente::ObtenerDatos(){
cout<<"Id de cliente: "<<endl;
cin>> id_cliente;

cout<<"Nombre del cliente: "<<endl;
cin>> nombre;

cout<<"Numero telefonico: "<<endl;
cin>>telefono;

cout<<"Direccion de cliente: "<<endl;
cin>> direccion;

cout<<"Tipo de servicio buscado: "<<endl;
cin>> servicio;
```

}

```
void Cliente::MostrarInfoCliente(){
    
    cout<<"\t Id de cliente: \n"                <<getId_cliente();
    cout<<"\t Nombre del cliente: \n"           <<getNombre();
    cout<<"\t Numero telefonico: \n"            <<getTelefono();
    cout<<"\t Direccion de cliente: \n"     <<getDireccion();
    cout<<"\t Tipo de servicio buscado: \n" <<getServicio();

}
```

Este es del Cliente.h

```
   #ifndef CLIENTE_H
#define CLIENTE_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cliente
{
    public:
        int     getId_cliente();
        string  getNombre();
        string  getTelefono();
        string  getDireccion();
        string  getServicio();
        
        int     setId_cliente(int id_cliente);
        string  setNombre(string nombre);
        string  setTelefono(string telefono);
        string  setDireccion(string direccion);
        string  setServicio(string servicio);
        
        Const(int id, string nombre, string telefono, string direccion, string servicio);
        void ObtenerDatos();
        void MostrarInfoCliente();
        
    private:
        int id_cliente;
        string nombre;
        string telefono;
        string direccion;
        string servicio;
        
};
```

Este es el main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "Cliente.h"
#include "Equipo.h"


using namespace std;
    void RegistroCliente();
    void RegistroEquipo();
    void InfoEquipo();
    void InfoCliente();
    void ModEquipo();
    Equipo arreglo2[1];
    Cliente arreglo1[1];
    
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    
char opcion=0;

do{
cout<<"Bienvenido al sistema de inventario \n"<<endl;
cout<<"Introduzca un numero para las siguientes opciones: \n"<<endl;
cout<<"\t 1. Registro Cliente"<<endl;
cout<<"\t 2. Registro de Equipo"<<endl;
cout<<"\t 3. Modificar Equipo"<<endl;
cout<<"\t 4. Informacion Clientes"<<endl;
cout<<"\t 5. Informacion Equipos"<<endl;
cout<<"\t 6. Salir"<<endl;
cin>>opcion;    

 switch(opcion)

   {

      case '1':
             RegistroCliente();

        break;

      case '2':
            RegistroEquipo();

        break;

      case '3':         

        cout<<"Prueba 3"<<endl;

        break;

      case '4':     
            InfoCliente();
            
        break;
        
      case '5': 
            InfoEquipo();
            
        break;
        
     case '6':      

        break;
        
    }

}while(opcion !='6');
return 0;
```

}

```
void RegistroCliente()
{
    int var=0;
    cout<<"Introduce el numero de clienes a registrar: "<<endl;
    cin>>var;       
    Cliente arreglo1[var];
    for (int i=0; i<var; i++)
    {
        arreglo1[i].ObtenerDatos();
    }
    
}



void InfoCliente(){
        int var=0;
        cout<<"Introduce el numero de clientes a visualizar: "<<endl;
        cin>>var;   
        
        for (int i=0; i<var; i++){
            arreglo1[i].MostrarInfoCliente();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí estás creando dos arreglos, cada arreglo tiene capacidad para almacenar exactamente 1 elemento:

```
Equipo arreglo2[1];
//              ^ capacidad para un único elemento

Cliente arreglo1[1];
//               ^ capacidad para un único elemento
```

Si intentas guardar más elementos acabarás escribiendo fuera de los límites de tu arreglo y eso implica que escribirás en posiciones de memoria que no pertenece a tu variable. Si estas posiciones pertenecen a otras variables sobreescribirás su contenido y eso hará que el programa se vuelva inestable.

El programa no se muere directamente porque estas variables están alojadas en la pila y esa región de memoria pertenece a tu programa. Si estuvieses trabajando con memoria dinámica lo normal es que esa memoria que no pertenece a tu array ni tan siquiera le pertenezca a tu programa. Los Sistemas Operativos modernos tienen la mala costumbre de impedir que un proceso corrompa la memoria de otros y, cuando detectan un acceso de este tipo, matan el proceso causante.

Pero lo dicho, tus variables están en la pila y el cómo gestiones la memoria interna de tu programa es cosa tuya.

Otro problema que tienes aquí es que estás usando, seguramente sin darte cuenta, variables locales:

```
void RegistroCliente()
{
    int var=0;
    cout<<"Introduce el numero de clienes a registrar: "<<endl;
    cin>>var;       
    Cliente arreglo1[var]; // <<--- Variable local
    for (int i=0; i<var; i++)
    {
        arreglo1[i].ObtenerDatos();
    }
}
```

Esta variable, la cual se llama exactamente igual que la variable global, lo que hace es precisamente ocultar a la variable global. Lo que está pasando aquí es que escribes en una variable que, cuando el programa abandone la función, dejará de existir.

Por otro lado, el tamaño de los arrays debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación. Un array cuyo tamaño solo se conoce en tiempo de ejecución se conoce como *Variable Length Array* o simplemente VLA y esta es una característica no soportada por el estándar. Si te funciona es porque tu compilador la soporta, pero no es una opción portable ni mucho menos deseada.

Piensa que los arrays se crean en la pila del programa. La pila es una región de memoria de tamaño limitado y, si se llena, el programa se muere. Nada me impediría crear un array de un millón de elementos y al hacerlo, la pila se desbordaría aunque tuviese 300TB de memoria RAM.

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar memoria dinámica:

```
Cliente * arreglo1 = nullptr;

void RegistroCliente()
{
    int var=0;
    cout<<"Introduce el numero de clienes a registrar: "<<endl;
    cin>>var;

    // Si el arreglo ya apuntaba a una región de memoria, la liberamos    
    if( arreglo1 != nullptr )
      delete[] arreglo1;

    // Hacemos la reserva del tamaño pedido
    arreglo1 = new Cliente[var];

    for (int i=0; i<var; i++)
    {
        arreglo1[i].ObtenerDatos();
    }
    
}
```

Aunque quizás sería más conveniente usar los contenedores de la STL y evitar la tediosa tarea de lidiar con la memoria dinámica directamente:

```
std::vector<Equipo> arreglo1;


void RegistroCliente()
{
    int var=0;
    cout<<"Introduce el numero de clienes a registrar: "<<endl;
    cin>>var;

    arreglo1.resize(var); // Adaptamos el tamaño de la colección 

    for (int i=0; i<var; i++)
    {
        arreglo1[i].ObtenerDatos();
    }
}
```

Y, por favor, usa nombres de variables con sentido. Nombes como `arreglo1` y `arreglo2` son una receta para el desastre en cuanto tu programa crezca un poco.